# Intermittent IdentityServer The Key {xxxx} Was Not Found in the Key Ring

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, blazor, identityserver4, azure-keyvault

I have a Blazor WASM app running in an Azure App Service running .NET Core 6. My data protection configuration looks like this:

```
var keyVaultSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("KeyVault").Get<KeyVaultSettings>();

builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(keyVaultSettings.ConnectionString, keyVaultSettings.ContainerName, keyVaultSettings.BlobName)
    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri(keyVaultSettings.KeyIdentifier), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

This works just fine ... for a while. Then one day every call will error out on the RemoteCryptographyClient.UnwrapKey call. I get a CryptographicException with the following detail:

**Message:**    The key {keyid} was not found in the key ring. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning
**Exception type:**  System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
**Failed method:**  Duende.IdentityServer.Services.KeyManagement.DataProtectionKeyProtector.Unprotect
**Operation name:** GET /.well-known/openid-configuration
**Problem Id:** System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException at Duende.IdentityServer.Services.KeyManagement.DataProtectionKeyProtector.Unprotect
Assembly    Duende.IdentityServer, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

**Call Stack:**

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore (Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect (Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DataProtectionCommonExtensions.Unprotect (Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Services.KeyManagement.DataProtectionKeyProtector.Unprotect (Duende.IdentityServer, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/IdentityServer/Services/Default/KeyManagement/DataProtectionKeyProtector.cs:56)
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Services.KeyManagement.KeyManager.<GetKeysFromStoreAsync>b__20_0 (Duende.IdentityServer, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/IdentityServer/Services/Default/KeyManagement/KeyManager.cs:426)
```

I believe this is due to some sort of caching / timeout issue, however I can't figure out exactly what/why/how to resolve it. To get things running again I need to restart the app service and then make sure I immediately hit the app from an incognito window. If I try to access it from a regular browsing window the error will persist (for all users) until I restart and hit the app from an incognito window at which point the service is restored for all users.

Comment: I am seeing this error too. More information about the issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/48848